# Is there a way for ediff to compare SVN changes in the head to my local copy?

Tags: ediff, version-control, svn

My company uses SVN, and one of the things I often want to do is compare the differences that someone else checked in without doing an update.  For example, if I see someone has committed a new version of foo.pl, and I want to compare what is in the HEAD compared to my local foo.pl, I could do this:

```
svn diff -r BASE:HEAD foo.pl
```

is there a vc-command that already does this?  I imagine if there was a way to load a buffer with the contents of BASE:HEAD foo.pl, then I could use ediff to compare the two buffers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the command `ediff-revision`, see the [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ediff/) for details.

Comment: Thanks!  Took a little messing around, but I got it working.  By default it compares my changes vs the revision I started from.  But if I change revision to "HEAD" I get exactly what I want.